# Disable ecdhe-rsa-des-cbc3-sha 112 bit on windows 2008 IIS

Tags: windows, iis

Our security team has asked to remove 
ecdhe-rsa-des-cbc3-sha 112 bit cipher on a application hosted in IIS / windows 2008

I tried to use IISCrypto but it does not show up in it's list .

Can anyone guide me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

I realized the URL of my server is load balanced . Loadbalancer also has its own certificate & cipher suit . 
I need to make this change on Loadbalancer